# How do you run a log on/off script when a client logs on with VNC

Tags: script, vnc, vncserver

How do you run a log on/off script when a client logs on with VNC?
I want to kill any instances of XMBC running as I log on to a machine. 
Is there a way to say when a client logs on, run a script, that, in my case, would kill any xbmc process.

Comment: Which version of VNC are you using?

Comment: Latest tight VNC server.